# $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$,$\phi(x,y)=x+iy=z$,$F=\phi^{-1}f\phi$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

$\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$ be a map $\phi(x,y)=x+iy=z$, let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be the function $f(z)=z^2$ and $F=\phi^{-1}f\phi$ then I need to say which of the following are correct.

1.The linear map $T(x,y)=2\left[\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{x}&{-y}\\
{y}&{x}\\
\end{array}\right]$ represents the derivative of $F$ at $(x,y)$

2.The linear map $T(x,y)=2\left[\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{x}&{y}\\
{y}&{x}\\
\end{array}\right]$ represents the derivative of $F$ at $(x,y)$

3. The linear transformation $T(z)=2z$ represents the derivative of $f$ at $z$

4.The linear transformation $T(z)=2z$ represents the derivative of $f$ at $z=0$

I have calculated myself that only $1$ nad $3$ are true. am I right?

Comment: Yes.............You are right...........

Comment: @ La Belle : Clearly 1. represent the derivative of $F$,I am little bit confused abut 3, please tell me  that how the 3. represent the derivative of $F$